# Update values in separate Collections with Firestore in a denormalised DB

Tags: database, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, consistency

I have two collections:

```
Collection c1
-- doc1
-- -- name: "doc1Name"
-- -- position: 1
-- doc2
-- -- name: "doc2Name"
-- -- position: 2

Collection c2
-- doc1
-- -- name: "name1"
-- -- reference: "doc1Name"
-- -- position: 1
-- doc2
-- -- name: "name2"
-- -- reference: "doc2Name"
-- -- position: 2
-- doc3
-- -- name: "name3"
-- -- reference: "doc2Name"
-- -- position: 2
```

If someone sets `c1.doc2.position = 3`, I need to update `c2.doc2.position` and `c2.doc3.position` to 3 as well.

However, Firestore does not allow to update fields based on a given condition, so I need to iterate all docs belonging to `c2` and update the `position` field when `reference = "doc2Name"`. If I use a batch write or a transaction, I can't query `C2` within their body, because if I do, Firestore returns an error like "*Transaction has already completed*.", due to the asynchronous nature of the listeners. And I can't update one of the two collections in the completion handler because that would leave the DB inconsistent if the second batch/transaction fails.

This a typical scenario when dealing with denormalised DBs, and denormalization is also quite common when dealing with Firestore. Is there any solution with Firestore that does not imply cloud functions?

Comment: Can you not make the query before performing the batch write?  (FYI Firestore does not have a capital S in its name.)

Comment: You mean a query that saves the references of all docs to edit? If that is the case, I can, but if the content of the collection changes during that delay I will still get inconsistency (I edited the capital S).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't atomically transact or batch on the dynamic results of some query.  You have to be able to identify all the documents before the transaction or batch begins.  You will have this issue no matter if you are writing from a mobile client or a server (including Cloud Functions, which might also process events out of your intended order).

Your only option might be to transaction on the entire contents of both collections, assuming they don't change size.  If the collection can change size at any time, then I don't think this particular model is going to work for your use case, as it's not possible to lock the entire database in order to prevent conflicting changes from occurring.

Comment: Yes, the batch update must involve the entire contents of both collections (they are not that big in fact). I must say, my use case (that is, updating two referenced collections atomically that might change in size) does not sound so specific to me.

Comment: It's a common request, but it's still not possible today. It actually doesn't matter that the documents are in different collections - you still have to identify all the documents to change atomically.  Feel free to file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time.